# Defer all file replacements until a reboot in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application installer created with Inno Setup that deploys multiple binaries and support files for my application.

When I perform an upgrade installation (e.g. run setup-1.5.exe while version 1.0 is already installed), some of the files from the previous version are frequently in-use, and cannot be replaced until the next reboot.  That is fine, Inno handles that case correctly.

However, the logic I really want is:  if any files cannot be replaced until the next reboot, then I want *all* files to be replaced on the next reboot.  Otherwise, binaries that are in use are not replaced but some support files might be, leaving the application in an unstable state prior to reboot anyway.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this?  I have not been able to find one, short of locking all the support files myself explicitly, which is quite ugly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno can't do this natively. This is why it provide `AppMutex` and friends to ensure that it's all clear, and if anything is left, it tells the user that they must reboot.

You can then expand on this in your app and refuse to start if a restart replace action is pending.

Comment: Thank you Deanna for your help, but this really doesn't meet my requirements.  AppMutex is used so that Inno can refuse to install/uninstall while the app is running, but what I really want is for my app to install/uninstall "transactionally", but for the "transaction" not to take effect until reboot.  So far as I can see, there isn't a way even to hack together that behavior using AppMutex.

Comment: The only way I can think of to hack together the desired behavior is to lock all the files in my app's installation explicitly, so that they are all replaced on reboot anyway.  This is a bit annoying, doesn't scale well going forward, doesn't provide similar functionality for registry data, etc.  Is there another way to accomplish my goal that I'm not seeing?  Thanks!

Comment: Not directly, but if you use a mutex, then you (should) guarantee that those files are free to be updated, with the mutex locked so nothing else can use them until the setup has finished, essentially using the mutex as the transaction lock (a mutual exclusion for lack of a better term :).

Comment: One can certainly use a mutex as a test to see if the executable binary is free to be updated, but the problem is how Inno responds to the mutex being unavailable -- it throws an error and fails the entire installation.  I don't think there is a way to simply "pend" the installation until reboot, without coding that logic myself (basically, locking every single file in the existing installation explicitly).  If that is the case, then indeed, there's no way to achieve my goal.

Comment: No, If you want to allow the app to continue to run, then Inno will try and replace what it can, leaving the rest till a reboot. You will need to do the check and add code to exit running the whole setup on a restart yourself.

Comment: Thanks Deanna.  I will accept this answer, I just wish there was a cleaner way provided by Inno.